# String boot: UriComponentsBuilder toString

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm running against an issue I guess it has to be easy to solve but I'm stuck on.

This is my code snippet:

```
String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("http://localhost")
    .build().toUriString();
```

The value of `url` is:

```
http:/localhost
```

As you can see, `://` is replaced by `:/`

Any ideas about how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fromPath` will take just an API or resource path like `/api/student`. But it does not take entire url as in your case. One alternative would be,

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://localhost")
                .build().toUriString();
```

Or else the same can be done using,

```
UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("http").host("localhost").build().toString();
```